# Java. Тип поля такой же как у имени класса

Tags: java

```
static class Node {
        boolean value;
        Node nextNode;
        public Node(boolean value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
```

Не подскажите что означает запись Node nextNode?

Comment: А что тут не ясно?

Comment: В классе `Node` есть поле `nextNode`, у которого тип `Node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылку на на такой же класс, как и этот. Так, например, устроены связанные списки
https://upread.ru/art.php?id=986

Вы должны понимать, что класс - это не что-то хранящееся в памяти, а лишь некий "шаблон" по которому следует построить какой-то реальный объект. Соответственно, ничего не запрещает в поле класса использовать этот же самый класс, потому что это просто шаблон

Приведу очень безобразный, но очень понятный пример (безобразный, потому что лучше приводить пример с реализацией связанного списка, а не вот так вот в тупую, но считаю, что это лишнее для объяснения)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node mainNode = new Node();
        mainNode.setName("TEST1");
        mainNode.setAge("TEST11");

        Node secondNode = new Node();
        secondNode.setName("TEST2");
        secondNode.setAge("TEST22");
        mainNode.setNode(secondNode);

        Node thirdNode = new Node();
        thirdNode.setName("TEST3");
        thirdNode.setAge("TEST33");
        secondNode.setNode(thirdNode);

        Node fourthNode = new Node();
        fourthNode.setName("TEST4");
        fourthNode.setAge("TEST44");
        thirdNode.setNode(fourthNode);

        Node currNode = mainNode;
        do {
            System.out.println(currNode.getName());
            System.out.println(currNode.getAge());

            currNode = currNode.getNode();
        } while (currNode != null);
    }

    private static class Node {

        private String name;
        private String age;

        private Node node;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public Node getNode() {
            return node;
        }

        public void setNode(Node node) {
            this.node = node;
        }
    }
```

Вы можете создавать сколько угодно классов Node и связывать их друг с другом, а потом в цикле do ... while просто идти от **ГЛАВНОГО** объекта до момента, пока вообще там не закончатся объекты

Comment: да, спасибо большое, что объяснили!) Отмечу как решение, как таймер позволит.